# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError after upgrading to kotlin RC1 (1.0.0-rc-1036)

Tags: android, kotlin

After upgrading to kotlin RC1 (1.0.0-rc-1036), I get this error:

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.lang.Object kotlin.Lazy.getValue()' was expected to be of type interface but instead was found to be of type virtual (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)

I use *lazy* in one of my class:

```
 val api by lazy {
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        ...
}
```

From the [release notes](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/build-1.0.0-rc-1036):

> Lazy is now an interface open for implementation

But I cannot figure out what I have to change to get my code running again...

Comment: Seems that you have compiled code with the new compiler, but running it with an old kotlin runtime in the classpath.

Comment: If you are using a build system like gradle or maven, post your configuration. If not check in your lib folder for `kotlin-stdlib-1.0.0-rc-1036.jar`

Answer (score 2):

When the code is being compiled against the standard library `kotlin-stdlib-1.0.0-rc-1036.jar` the compiler sees `Lazy` to be an interface and generates `INVOKEINTERFACE` instruction to get the value of its property:

```
INVOKEINTERFACE kotlin/Lazy.getValue ()Ljava/lang/Object;
```

In case if at run-time you get `Lazy` loaded from the pre-RC standard library it occurs to be a class and not an interface. Here is where JVM catches that inconsistency and throws an `IncompatibleClassChangeError`.

So you need to ensure you don't have an old standard library available to classloader at run-time.

If you use Gradle, follow the instructions at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#configuring-dependencies to configure/update dependency on the standard library.